# Average using loops

Tags: python, loops

```
average = total / count
while PEnd !="Q" :
    total = total + value
    average = 0.0
    value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
    total = total + value
    count = 1
     value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
     PEnd = input("Enter character Q to quit or any other character to continue:
    ")
    PEnd = " "
    PEnd = input("Enter character Q to quit or any other character to continue: ")
    total = 0
     count = count + 1
    print("The average is: ", average)
```

Anyone know how to rearrange this code so that when the values that are inputted are 3 4 8 4 , the average is 4.75. have tried rewriting it and getting average as 2 with code below and 4 when count = 0

here's my try:

```
PEnd = " "
while PEnd !="Q" :
    value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
    average = 0.0
    total = 0
    count = 1
    total = total + value
    count = count + 1
    average = total / count

    PEnd = input("Enter character Q to quit or any other character to continue: ")
    
print("The average is: ", average)
```

Comment: `count = 0` must be BEFORE the loop. Your code sets it back to 1 each time through the loop.

Comment: `average = total / count` should be after the loop.

Comment: `total = 0` must also be before the loop. This is a common beginner mistake, but it seems like it should be obvious.

Comment: @Barmar that probably doesnt matter though really(calculating avg each iteration)? ... other than adding some unnecessary computations

Comment: @JoranBeasley That's why I said should rather than must :)

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the help your comments completely resolved my problem; I am, as you probably noticed, a beginner in loops and am wondering what's the difference between having `average = total/count` outside the loop and having it inside the loop.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the average until you have all the data. So why do it in the loop with only partial data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing the variables before you start your while loop (see below).

```
PEnd = " "
count = 0
total = 0
while PEnd !="Q" :
    value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
    total += value
    count += 1
    PEnd = input("Enter character Q to quit or any other character to continue: ")
average = total / count
    
print("The average is: ", average)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. was wondering if 'average= total/count' should go outside of the loop, would it make it run better?

Comment: yes that's a good point. You're not using it each iteration so it could go outside of the loop. It wouldn't actually make it run any better, but you reduce the computations per loop and it looks cleaner :)

Comment: you actually don't need to initialize it till you use it- I've edited the solution to show how

Answer (score 1):

break your program into its parts

1. get a bunch of integers from the user
2. average those numbers
3. print the result

It helps me to actually break my program into its logical components so i would start with just getting a list of numbers

```
import re
def get_ints():
    while True:
       user_input = input("enter a number or numbers(or nothing to quit)")
       if not user_input:
          break
       for a_number in re.findall("\d+",user_input):
           yield int(a_number)

a_bunch_of_numbers = list(get_ints())
# you could enter 1 number at a time or a list of numbers seperated by non-numbers
print(a_bunch_of_numbers) # looks right :)
```

assuming(and verifying) that part works i move on to the next part of creating the average

```
average = sum(a_bunch_of_numbers)/len(a_bunch_of_numbers)
# or numpy.mean(a_bunch_of_numbers)
```

finally all i need to do is print the result